# Passing an empty CWD to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

.I want to pass cwd into a method that uses subprocess.

Setting a var like this :

`cwd = kwargs.get('cwd')`

Then using it later in the method like this :

```
process = subprocess.Popen(list(command), 
                        shell=False,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        cwd=cwd)
```

I want to be able to set a default if no kwarg 'cwd' is passed. The purpose is to create clear and simple code, and avoid an if statement.

Without a default in kwargs.get I get an error :

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'None'`

Comment: Clearly, your `kwargs` does not contain `"cwd"`, or `kwargs["cwd"]` is `None`.

Comment: @NPE - I've re-clarified my question a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to set the default kwarg `cwd` to `None`

`cwd = kwargs.get('cwd',None)`

Comment: `kwargs.get('cwd')` and `kwargs.get('cwd', None)` should produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Check the calling part of the funciton. `cwd=None` should just work.

```
>>> subprocess.call(['ls'], cwd=None)
0
```

I suspect the caller is passing a string `'None'`.

```
>>> subprocess.call(['ls'], cwd='None')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'None'
```